# Solidity function returns [object Object]

Tags: solidity, web3js

When I run my solidity function, it's supposed to return a string - but it returns `[object Object]` 
I'm calling the function in my frontend and logging the result of the function call.

Here is my solidity function call

```
function getResult() returns(string) {
  return result;
}
```

This is what I have on the frontend

```
async getResult() {
  let contractInstance = await MyContract.at(this.state.contractAddress)
  let result = await contractInstance.getResult()
  console.log(`This is the result ${result}`);
}
```

Comment: Why don't you print `JSON.stringify(result, null, 4)` and find out exactly what is "inside" that object?

Answer (score 2):

This would do:

```
async getResult() {
  let contractInstance = await MyContract.at(this.state.contractAddress);
  let result = await contractInstance.getResult().call();
  console.log(`This is the result ${result}`);
}
```

Functions that do not require a transaction to be sent can be called directly.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript returns [object Object] when you log out variables that are objects in templates or string concatenations. If you `console.log('This is the result ', result);` it will return the object itself, which will contain the string you are looking for.

The object will probably look like

```
{
    0: 'result'
}
```

Comment: So I need to do `result[0]` ?

Comment: Did you try logging out the result and checking? I think that `result[0]` will work, but I can't be sure off the top of my head.

Comment: Yeah, I tried it and it returned undefined

Comment: Sorry to ask so many clarifying questions, you're saying that `result` returned undefined, or `result[0]` returned undefined?

Comment: `result` returns undefined and `result[0]` throws an error because you can't have an index of 0 for undefined

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, the problem is this line here:

```
let result = await contractInstance.getResult()
```

should be

```
let result = await contractInstance.getResult().call()
```

if you want to have a look at the json you can use `inspect`

```
import {inspect} from 'util'
console.log(inspect(result))
```

Answer (score 0):

I have worked with web3JS (NodeJS). you can use this:

```
const Web3 = require("web3")
const web3 = new Web3("https://rpc-provider.....")

var MyContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, address);
MyContract.methods.getResult().call()
.then(console.log);
```

it will definitly console.log the string you want.

make sure you passed RPC-Provider, ABI & Contract Address.